# Dataflow job through Airflow DAG

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to execute apache beam pipeline python file using dataflow runner through BashOperator in Airflow. I've got the idea how to pass the parameters dynamically to the python file. I'm looking forward to optimize parameter - to avoid sending of all the parameters separately.
Example snippet:

**text_context.py**

```
import sys

def run_awc_orders(*args, **kwargs):
    print("all arguments -> ",  args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("all params -> ", sys.argv)
    run_awc_orders( sys.argv[1],  sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

**my_dag.py**

```
test_DF_job = BashOperator(
    task_id='test_DF_job',
    provide_context=True,
    bash_command="python /usr/local/airflow/dags/test_context.py {{ execution_date }} {{ next_execution_date }} {{ params.db_params.new_text }}  --runner DataflowRunner --key path_to_creds_json_file --project project_name --staging_location staging_gcp_bucket_location --temp_location=temp_gcp_bucket_location --job_name test-job",
    params={
              'db_params': {
                'new_text': 'Hello World'
              }
            },
    dag=dag
)
```

So, this is what we can see in the logs on airflow UI.

```
[2019-09-25 06:44:44,103] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - all params ->  ['/usr/local/airflow/dags/test_context.py', '2019-09-23T00:00:00+00:00', '2019-09-24T00:00:00+00:00', '127.0.0.1']
[2019-09-25 06:44:44,103] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - all arguments ->  ('2019-09-23T00:00:00+00:00', '2019-09-24T00:00:00+00:00', '127.0.0.1')
[2019-09-25 06:44:44,106] {bash_operator.py:132} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share exactly what is your question? Also, just FYI, Airflow has a DataflowOperator that allows you to launch a Dataflow job template.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo for sharing. I'm using DataflowTemplateOperator and it's working perfectly. I've tried DataflowPythonOperator as well with Python V.3+ inside the docker and receiving apache-beam module not found issue even though it's installed inside the container. So I would like to give it a try through BashOperator.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. It sounds like an issue to look into with the Airflow execution environment : /

Answer (score 1):

I believe the recommended way of doing this is with [Airflow's `DataflowPythonOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator.DataFlowPythonOperator), which receives Python and Dataflow options directly.

You'd do something like so:

```
test_DF_job = DataflowPythonOperator(
  py_file='/usr/local/airflow/dags/test_context.py',
  py_options=[...],
  dataflow_default_options={...},
  dag=dag
)
```

Comment: How would this work for a pipeline which is a module? 

I am assuming you just need to install the pipeline module in your airflow environment and then specify the python file to run the pipeline?